# How to prevent react page refresh when file changes in public folder

Tags: reactjs, flask

I'm developing a react project where I have a JSON file in public folder which changes the content each time I fetch new data with flask API. The problem is that the whole page reloads while I only want a component related to that JSON file to change not the whole page
what you suggest me to do please ?

Comment: Are you running your `React` project in development mode? If so, that's the intended behavior, assuming you use something like `create-react-app`.

Comment: what is the dev mode and how to disable it ?

Comment: Are you using `create-react-app`?

Comment: of course I have used in the first time I had created my project

Comment: Then you should read the docs for creating a deployment bundle - https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. Have you found any solutions to this?